# Closing a JarURLConnection

Tags: java, jar, urlconnection

Using a JarURLConnection I am able to read a file (e.g. *version.txt*) from a JAR *hosted on Dropbox* using the following code structure:

```
public static void checkForUpdates() {
    JarURLConnection jarConn = null;
    try {

        System.out.println("Checking for updates..");

        URL updateURL = new URL("jar:https://www.dropbox.com/s/.../foo.jar?dl=1!/version.txt");
        jarConn = (JarURLConnection) updateURL.openConnection();
        JarFile jarFile = jarConn.getJarFile();
        InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarConn.getJarEntry());
        BufferedReader versionTXT = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        /* Version comparing left out */

        // If there is an update:
        System.out.println("Update found!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (jarConn != null) {
            // This doesn't seem to work
            jarConn.getInputStream().close();
        }
    }
}
```

It works correctly when I call this method for the first time; you can see a delay between the "checking for updates"-message and the "result"-message.

When I upload a new foo.jar on Dropbox, and run the checkForUpdates() method again (*without* restarting the JVM), it will use the 'old' jar, and there is no delay between the checking & result messages. When I *do* restart the JVM, it will use the 'new' jar and show delay between the messages.

Is there any way to close the JarURLConnection, other than closing the InputStream (which doesn't seem to work)?

***I have tried the following things:***

- **Closing the JarURLConnection's OutputStream** -> Throws an error saying that the connection doesn't have an OutputStream.
- **Closing the URLConnections Input- & OutputStream** (by creating a new variable before I cast it to a JarURLConnection) -> Closing the InputStream doesn't seem to do anything and closing the OutputStream throws the same error.
- **Closing the BufferedReader** -> No effect.

If it's not possible to close the JarURLConnection, is it possible to create a new one that *does* reconnect? Restarting the JVM apparently does something that it does reconnect, is it possible to simulate that *without* restarting the JVM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do a try - resource instead? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I just tested a try-resource on my InputStream and BufferedReader, but there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JarURLConnection` uses a cache for jar files. Therefore you see no delay in the second attempt.

So simply turn off the cache before you access the Jar file:

```
JarURLConnection con = ...;
con.setUseCaches(false);
JarFile jarFile = jarConn.getJarFile();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just figured this out as well, and I reloaded this page to see your answer which was just posted. I will accept this as answer, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question:

[URLConnection cache prevents updating JARs with the JarArchiveRepository](https://github.com/Netflix/Nicobar/issues/37)

> The only workaround I found is to disable JarURLConnection caching and
>   it then works as expected:
>
> ```
> urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
> ```

You can see the [Sun code here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java.html):

```
public void connect() throws IOException {
    if (!connected) {
        /* the factory call will do the security checks */
        jarFile = factory.get(getJarFileURL(), getUseCaches());

        /* we also ask the factory the permission that was required
         * to get the jarFile, and set it as our permission.
         */
        if (getUseCaches()) {
            jarFileURLConnection = factory.getConnection(jarFile);
        }

        if ((entryName != null)) {
            jarEntry = (JarEntry)jarFile.getEntry(entryName);
            if (jarEntry == null) {
                try {
                    if (!getUseCaches()) {
                        jarFile.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                throw new FileNotFoundException("JAR entry " + entryName + " not found in " + jarFile.getName());
            }
        }
        connected = true;
    }
}
```